# Call/embed wordpress post outside loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

Permalink of post set to:

```
<a href="/?link=<?php echo get_permalink( $postid ); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

By example it comes to this:

```
http://website.com/?link=http://website.com./post-example/
```

I want to stay on home page, and now I need code to embed content of `http://website.com./post-example/`, nice thing is we have post tag `post-example`.

By this tag am I able now to call and embed this post inside home page?
`$_GET['link']` will get `http://website.com./post-example/`

Now how do I call this post?
Any solutions?
And it should be like:
If `?link=`exist in url, call this function (embed post with title and content), otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have the post's ID. (**$postid**)

If you have a post's ID and want to display anything from a specific post you can do this:

```
<?php $my_special_post = get_post($postid, ARRAY_A); ?>
```

After that you can display anything from the post's properties. For example:

```
<?php echo $my_special_post['post_title']; ?>
<?php echo $my_special_post['post_content']; ?>
```

And place them in whatever html tags you want.

The url segment "post-example" is not a tag. It's the post's "**slug**" or **post_name** property. Here you can read more about the **$post** object and his properties:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post

Hope that helps.